# Laravel 5.1 error when trying to pass variable to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following snippet of code, where I am trying to pass the `email` object to my view.

```
return response()->view('admin.editEmail')->with('email', $this->template->findTemplateById($id));
```

This results in the following error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::with()

How can I fix this?

Comment: It is not necessary to use response(), it will work by just using view('admin.editEmail')->with(...)

Answer (score 2):

Just pass it as a second parameter in `view()`:

```
return response()->view('admin.editEmail', $email);
```

Comment: @V4n1ll4 If this  helped you, then please mark this answer as right

Answer (score 1):

[Here are the docs for view->with()](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Contracts/View/View.html#method_with). You have to pass a key and a value for each variable you send. If you have multiple, you need to send an array of keys=>values. `compact` is useful for this.

`$template = $this->template->findTemplateById($id)`

`response()->view('admin.editEmail')->with(compact('email', 'template'));`

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of doing this.

I prefer to use this one as you can easily add new variables.
In this way its also posible to have different variable names in your controller and view.

```
return view('admin.editEmail', [
    'email' => $adminEmail,
    'anotherVar' => $someValue,
]);
```

In this example the email in the controller is stored in `$adminEmail` but in the template we will receive it as `$email`.

With compact you need to have the same variable name in your controller as in your view.